# org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'username' is not present

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp

I am trying to build a login page using JSP and Springboot v.4. Even though the parameters are passed correctly from login.JSP, the username parameter is becoming null. I tried with getting method and could see the username value correctly in query parameters, but still the same exception. Why the username is not passing the correct value? Below is the exception.

```
2020-12-18 10:49:10.826 DEBUG 6364 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.nive.springboot.todoapp.controller.LoginController#showWelcomePage(String, String, ModelMap)
2020-12-18 10:49:10.832 DEBUG 6364 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Could not resolve parameter [0] in public java.lang.String com.nive.springboot.todoapp.controller.LoginController.showWelcomePage(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap): Required String parameter 'username' is not present
2020-12-18 10:49:10.835  WARN 6364 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'username' is not present]
2020-12-18 10:49:10.835 DEBUG 6364 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 400 BAD_REQUEST
```

Code:

```html
<%@ include file="common/header.jspf" %>
<%@ include file="common/navigation.jspf" %>

<div class="container">

    <font color="red">${errorMessage}</font>
    <form action="/login" method="post">
        Name : <input type="text" name="name" />
        Password : <input type="password" name="password" /> 
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
<%@ include file="common/footer.jspf" %>
```

```java
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("username")
public class LoginController {
    
    @Autowired
    LoginService service;
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLoginPage(ModelMap model){
        return "login";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String showWelcomePage(@RequestParam String username,@RequestParam String password,ModelMap model){
        
        int isValidUser = service.validateUser(username, password);
        
        switch(isValidUser) {
        case 0: model.put("errorMessage", "User doesn't exist");
        return "register";
        case -1:model.put("errorMessage", "invalid credentials");
        return "login";
        }
    
        model.put("username", username);
        model.put("password", password);
        
        return "welcome";
    }

}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "email", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Email(message = "*Please provide a valid Email")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide an email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    @Length(min = 5, message = "*Your password must have at least 5 characters")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your password")
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @Length(min = 5, message = "*Your username must have at least 5 characters")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your name")
   
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "name")
@NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
   @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your last name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "active", nullable = false)
    private int active;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Collection<Todo> todo;
    
    public User() {
        
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(int active) {
        this.active = active;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

modify jsp:    `Name : <input type="text" name="name" />` to `Name : <input type="text" name="username" />`

or
java:

```
public String showWelcomePage(@RequestParam String username,@RequestParam String password,ModelMap model){
```

to

```
public String showWelcomePage(@RequestParam("name") String username,@RequestParam String password,ModelMap model){
```

Comment: this is correct answer, adding the ("name") resolved the trick

Answer (score 0):

When submitting data in a form, the back-end code reads the value of the name attribute.
You can modify the code like this:

```
<%@ include file="common/header.jspf" %>
<%@ include file="common/navigation.jspf" %>

<div class="container">

    <font color="red">${errorMessage}</font>
    <form action="/login" method="post">
        Name : <input type="text" name="username" />
        Password : <input type="password" name="password" /> 
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
<%@ include file="common/footer.jspf" %>   
``
```